# How to properly append a list to a DataFrame in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm attempting to add every item in a list of strings (lines from a file) to my DataFrame. The line is filled with keys and values dumped into a list and converted to json. The issue is I cant get pandas to properly make a DataFrame from the list in the loop (code gets stuck in for loop).

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
with open(log_file_path, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = json.loads(line[1:])
        items = line.items() 
        all_list.append(list)

        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame.from_records([line])) 

        continue
print("work")
print(df)
print(df.head())
```

Here is what each line looks like.

```
line = {'protocol': 'https', 'instanceid': 'beacond-lga13-1349-12003', 'raw_data': 'i|200|122!i|200|114!i|200|117', 'source_ip': '90.227.61.0', 'ts': 1549434199, 'jobid': '1uxw9ir', 'geocode': 'SE', 'referer': 'https://sv.cam4.com/female', 'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-G935F/G935FXXS3ERL4 Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/8.2 Chrome/63.0.3239.111 Mobile Safari/537.36', 'appid': '157pr4o', 'app_version': 1536174158, 'asn': 3301}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can read your list in if i do it like this:

```
line = {'protocol': 'https', 'instanceid': 'beacond-lga13-1349-12003', 'raw_data': 'i|200|122!i|200|114!i|200|117', 'source_ip': '90.227.61.0', 'ts': 1549434199, 'jobid': '1uxw9ir', 'geocode': 'SE', 'referer': 'https://sv.cam4.com/female', 'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-G935F/G935FXXS3ERL4 Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/8.2 Chrome/63.0.3239.111 Mobile Safari/537.36', 'appid': '157pr4o', 'app_version': 1536174158, 'asn': 3301}


pd.DataFrame(line, index=[0])
```

You can use range in the index column index=range(0,len(items)) possibly as well,

```
lines = [{'protocol': 'https',
 'instanceid': 'beacond-lga13-1349-12003',
 'raw_data': 'i|200|122!i|200|114!i|200|117',
 'source_ip': '90.227.61.0',
 'ts': 1549434199,
 'jobid': '1uxw9ir',
 'geocode': 'SE',
 'referer': 'https://sv.cam4.com/female',
 'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-G935F/G935FXXS3ERL4 Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/8.2 Chrome/63.0.3239.111 Mobile Safari/537.36',
 'appid': '157pr4o',
 'app_version': 1536174158,
 'asn': 3301},
{'protocol': 'https',
 'instanceid': 'beacond-lga14-1349-12003',
 'raw_data': 'i|200|122!i|200|114!i|200|117',
 'source_ip': '90.227.61.1',
 'ts': 1549434199,
 'jobid': '1uxw9ir',
 'geocode': 'SE',
 'referer': 'https://sv.cam4.com/female',
 'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-G935F/G935FXXS3ERL4 Build/R16NW) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/8.2 Chrome/63.0.3239.111 Mobile Safari/537.36',
 'appid': '157pr4o',
 'app_version': 1536174158,
 'asn': 3301}]

pd.DataFrame(lines, index=list(range(0, len(lines))))
```

output:

```
Out[899]: 
  protocol                instanceid                       raw_data    source_ip          ts  ...                     referer                                         user_agent    appid app_version   asn
0    https  beacond-lga13-1349-12003  i|200|122!i|200|114!i|200|117  90.227.61.0  1549434199  ...  https://sv.cam4.com/female  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-...  157pr4o  1536174158  3301
1    https  beacond-lga14-1349-12003  i|200|122!i|200|114!i|200|117  90.227.61.1  1549434199  ...  https://sv.cam4.com/female  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SAMSUNG SM-...  157pr4o  1536174158  3301

[2 rows x 12 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a list of lists and THEN construct your dataframe. For example:

```py
# After collecting each list
lists = [['a', 'b'], 
['c', 'd']]
# Pass your list of lists (and you can name the columns too if you like!)
pd.DataFrame(lists, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    c    d
```

Comment: i would assume you are talking about the keys and values in this case.

Comment: For each line in your json, you're getting a list right?

Comment: I have a method to write all the keys and values to a list, yes.

Comment: ok great! So from your example, it looks like you are appending the list from each line to `all_list`, right? You can then take `all_list` and make a dataframe with `pd.DataFrame(all_list)`

Comment: Essentially, `pd.DataFrame(list of lists)` will give you a dataframe, so first make your list of lists and then you can make the dataframe